# Induction question with 'if' statement

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

I have an induction homework question that I got stuck in the middle.

Prove by induction that if $a + a^{-1} \in \Bbb{Z}$ then for each $n \in \Bbb{N}$ the following is true:
$$a^{n} + a^{-n} \in \Bbb{Z}$$

If possible, I would like to understand the method for solving those kind of questions (I know induction, but the "if" part at the begining confuses me)

Thanks in advance,
Ron

Comment: I'm guessing this assignment is not in English? Otherwise this is an incorrect use of the term "field."

Comment: I don't see why the if botter you... Suppose that $a^n+a^{-n}\in \Bbb Z$ for some $n\in \Bbb N$ and show that $a^{n+1}+a^{-(n+1)}\in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Take a look at how I edited your question to see how to use some basic LaTeX.

Comment: The 'if' bit kind of makes the problem easier. You're being given the base case $a+a^{-1}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and you just need to do the inductive step

Comment: Thank you all, for the help and comments. Yes, the assignment was not in english, I searched wikipedia for the right term and came across http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29.
graydad - Thanks for the editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have $a^1+a^{-1}\in\mathbb Z$ and $a^2+a^{-2}=(a^1+a^{-1})^2-2\in\mathbb Z$.

Suppose $a^k+a^{-k}\in\mathbb Z$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z^+, k\le n$, where $a^n+a^{-n}\in\mathbb Z$.

We will prove that then $a^{n+1}+a^{-(n+1)}\in\mathbb Z$ (so your statement follows by strong induction).

$$(a+a^{-1})(a^n+a^{-n})-(a^{n-1}+a^{-(n-1)})=(a^{n+1}+a^{-(n+1)})\in\mathbb Z\ \ \ \square$$

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to:

> Show for any $a$ where $a+a^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}$ that $a^n+a^{-n} \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

If you need to prove a claim of the form

> If $A$ then $B$

you start off with "assume $A$." From there you proceed to do whatever you need to do to arrive at $B$. In the context of your problem, all you have to do is say something along the lines of "suppose $a$ is such that $a+a^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}$." If you are proving this with induction, that will complete the base case. Then in a similar fashion you state the induction hypothesis. "Suppose for all $n \in \{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ that $a^{n}+a^{-n} \in \mathbb{Z}$." Now proceed from here to do whatever you need to do to show $a^{k+1}+a^{-(k+1)} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now. I marked the other answer for future readers, maybe they'll need the answer itself rather then the way to solve.

Comment: @RonGross Do you understand the solution?